# Using Terraform how can I create a user for each database as well as for each namespace?

Tags: foreach, nested, terraform

My Terraform script currently creates 2 databases for a set of namespaces (1 or more).  I now need to create a user for each respective database, and I am having trouble figuring out the correct method to do this.

This is what I have currently...

```
variable "namespaces" {
  type = set(string)
}

variable "databases" {
  type = set("server", "analyzer")
}

resource "postgresql_database" "server_databases" {
  for_each          = toset(var.namespaces)
  name              = "server_${each.key}"
}

resource "postgresql_database" "analyzer_databases" {
  for_each          = toset(var.namespaces)
  name              = "analyzer_${each.key}"
}

resource "random_password" "postgres_password" {
  length = 12
}

resource "postgresql_role" "read_only_user" {
  name                = "readonlyuser"
  login               = true
  password            = random_password.postgres_password.result
  skip_reassign_owned = true
}

resource "postgresql_grant" "readonly_tables" {
  depends_on  = [postgresql_database.server_databases, postgresql_database.analyzer_databases]
  for_each    = toset(var.namespaces)
  database    = "server_${each.key}"
  object_type = "table"
  privileges  = ["SELECT"]
  role        = "readonlyuser"
  schema      = "public"
}
```

The problem here is `database    = "server_${each.key}"` will only create a user for my server database in each namespace.  I am pretty sure I need a nested for_each but I am not sure how to achieve this.

I think it should even be possible to loop over the `postgresql_database` resources instead of having 2 separate resource's defined

Comment: You can iterate over the users instead of the namespaces.

Comment: can't, namespaces can have multiple values that I iterate over